# On the privileges page the tooltip is "unknown"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, tooltips

A cosmetic issue on the [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) page.

**Actual behavior**
When you hover over a documentation icon in the list a tooltip "unknown" appears.

See the actual (wrong) code

```
<i class="icon icon-documentation" title="unknown"></i>
```

**Expected behavior**
When you hover over a documentation icon a tooltip "documentation" appears.

Browser: Chrome; OS: Ubuntu.

Comment: Repro on Chrome 53.0.2785.103 on Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This will be fixed in production as of the next build.